# Why is it required to provide setting values in all cscfg files for every setting in Azure csdef file?

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

If any of the `cscfg` files do not provide value for a setting defined in `csdef`, following error is given:

> Role: 'Role1', setting 'Setting1' in the service definition could not be found in this service configuration.

If I have 10 `cscfg` files, for different environments e.g. Prod1, Prod2, it means that every time I introduce a new setting, I have to provide a value for the same in all 10 `cscfg` files. Many settings are optional and the code has a fallback default value. Even if code is not handling non existence of configuration value, shouldn't there be an easy way to define a default value for configuration in `csdef` itself and let cscfgs override if they need to?

Comment: `there be an easy way to define a default value for configuration in csdef itself and let cscfgs override if they need to?` Based on my experience, it  seems that it is not supported us to do that currently.